# Laravel map to return single value shows as object, not as string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, casting, laravel-blade

Within my view, I am displaying a value but it's showing as an object: `["Jamie Rogers"]`. I want to remove the `[" ... "]`part.

**Function:**

```
$auditor = $audit->map(function ($user) {
    return $user->name;
});
```

**Initial structure of Audit:**

```
Collection {#432 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Score {#410 ▼
      #table: "scores"
      #fillable: array:3 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:9 [▶]
      #original: array:9 [▼
        "id" => 5
        "score" => 0.11
        "name" => "Jamie Rogers"
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => "2017-03-19 17:47:23"
      ]
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
  ]
}
```

If I cast the value, using `return (string) $user->name`, it doesn't change it.

Comment: Can you provide the initial structure of `$audit`?

Comment: @manniL, added to the initial description.

Comment: Alright. Another, maybe even better, approach than `map` would be `$auditor = $audit->pluck('name');`. Does this work for you? You can get the first element of the result collection with `$auditor->first();`

Comment: Thanks @manniL, it looks much tidier! Unfortunately, it still shows `["Jamie Rogers"]`.

Comment: Even when you use `$auditor->first()`?

Comment: If I use `$auditor = $audit->first()->pluck('name');`, it actually returns all of the names within (I think) the table .. `["Mandy Taylor","Owen Butler","Joe Hill","Charles Griffiths","Thomas Hill","Pete Evans","Finley Cook",`.

Comment: Swap the statements :) `$auditor = $audit->pluck('name')->first();` Another option would be `$auditor = $audit->pluck('name')->toArray()[0]`, but this looks a bit dirty to me :D

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! If you add it to an answer I can approve it for you :)

Comment: You are welcome :) I posted the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first (and only) object of the collection, use the `pluck` method, followed by the `first` method:

```
$auditor = $audit->pluck('name')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

A **`map`** function is available on **`collection`** when you map on a collection it means that you want to do something with the data & return the processed data e.g you have first name & last name now in your API you want to response as full name

```
    $collection->map(function($value, $key) {//https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map
        return [
            'full_name' => $value->firstName . ' ' . $value->lastname
        ]
    });
```

In **`map`** function you pass function will get two **`value`** first is value & second is the **`key`**.

so in your case you can also do it in this way also

```
    $collection->map(function($value, $key) {
        return [
            'name' => $value->name
        ]
    })->first();
```

But for less coding [manniL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42890650/1025130) is more better then me.

In **`pluck`** you can get a key value like **`array_column`** but unlike **`pluck`** works on collections only. You can also tell **`pluck`** method to what will be the key for values if you pass a second parameter the key will be the value of that column. Also like to mention **`pluck`** also return a **`collection`** object. So you can use all the methods like **`first`** on that object.